optimization.splitChunks,How to configure the package.json module?
enter image description here
How to configure the package.json module?
How to configure the package.json module?
json

 output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/esm'),
      filename: '[name].esm.js ', // 使用动态占位符
      filename: (pathData) => {
        console.log('pathData', pathData);
        const name = pathData.chunk.name || 'default';  // 获取 chunk 名称
        if (name === 'app') {
          return 'sdk3.esm.js';
        }
        return `${name}.esm.js`; 
      },
      library: {
        type: 'module'
      },
    },



//dont have name 'main'/'app'
